# Как найти информацию из двух таблиц?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, phpmyadmin

Как найти информацию из двух таблиц, как сделать выборку?

Допустим, нам нужно найти **userid** по **определённым параметрам**: 
 у него должен быть цвет "**blue**" и имя должно быть "**Bob_name2**".

**Примечание**:

У пользователя под номером "**2**", имеется два имени.

Как правильно можно это сделать?

**Первая таблица**:

```
 |--------------|-----------|
 |userid        |color_name |
 |--------------|-----------|
 |1             |red        |
 |--------------|-----------|
 |2             |blue       |
 |--------------|-----------|
 |3             |red        |
 |--------------|-----------|
 |и.т.д.        | и.т.д     |
```

**Вторая таблица**:

```
|--------------|-----------|
|userid        |List_name  |
|--------------|-----------|
|1             |Tom        |
|--------------|-----------|
|2             |Rise       |
|--------------|-----------|
|3             |Yura       |
|--------------|-----------|
|2             |Bob_name2  |
|--------------|-----------|
| и.т.д        |и.т.д      |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если действительно только userid то так:

```
select distinct A.userid
  from table1 A, table2 B
 where A.userid=B.userid
   and A.color_name='red' and B.List_name='Bob_name2'
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33225/discussion-on-answer-by-mike------).